# Gigabyte GTX 660 OC 2GB running fine for short periods of time then causing critical errors and turning off. What's the cause of it?

Tags: graphics-card, fan, capacitor

I've purchased an used, partially damaged card - Gigabyte GTX 660 OC 2GB with twinfrozr fans. I had hope to easily repair it using my experience with electronics. However, the problem with it is bigger than I've initially thought. Allow me to explain:

The card behaves in an unusual way even for a damaged unit.

1. Upon booting up it can work for various amounts of time and then stop one of it's fans.
2. Temperatures are stable, nothing crazy.
3. After some additional time second fan stops and computer reboots without giving any beep signals.
4. After that, during initial boot up (bios screen and so on) fans do not begin to run. I am able to see what's on the screen due to the fact that my CPU has an integrated Intel HD 3000 graphics.
5. When I run GpuZ and search for my GTX 660, I only see integrated graphics.
6. I've checked what actually happened in windows event log manager and if I remember well, the error code was either 41 or 43. It was a critical error that prevented system from operating normally.
7. At this moment if I turn off the computer or reboot it - there is a very low chance for GTX 660 to begin working.
8. If I wait some time (about 30 minutes since the critical error) then GTX 660 begins to work until same scenario occurs.
9. The card itself behaves this way regardless of software running at certain moment. It can be during idle or browsing internet or eventually gaming (battlefield 4)

Additional info:

1. When both fans work, one is having problems with keeping up fixed RPMs. It's visible when I point a flashlight on it's blades. Second fan runs smoothly.
2. One of the fans makes a slight rubbing/rattling sound.
3. Previous owner didn't state when these problems started to occur.
4. Previous owner tested this card on Corsair's 750 Watt PSU and much newer components like mobo, CPU etc. He had the same situation.
5. Additional power connector is inserted in the GPU.
6. Upon disassembling the GPU (taking off the radiator and fans), I've noticed that little black boxes with 'R22' written on them (power coils) are having some dark stains. Stains look like as if someone smeared their matte finish with an oily substance. Upon cleaning with alcohol stains do not color the cotton-wool tip. However, they do disappear upon cleaning.
7. All capacitors seem to be ok. These are the japanese type caps that are supposed to be more durable. No burns, stains, or popped heads.

PC SPECS:
1. Mobo - Gigabyte GA-H61m-D2-B3 rev. 1.0
2. CPU - Intel i3-2120 LGA 1155 running 2x 3,3 Ghz
3. GPU - Intel HD 3000/Gigabyte GTX 660 OC 2GB Twinfrozr edition
4. SSD/HDD - 2 SSD + 1 HDD (Samsung, Kingston, Seagate)
5. PSU - Corsair VS 450

Photos of the unit:

Hotlink to gallery :

http://postimg.org/gallery/2cqw9mqr6/

Question: What is causing this card to fail? What electronic component can interfere with it's normal operation?

Comment: If the fan is not working then the GPU will more or less instantly overheat.  Its sounds like a circuit level problem, which isn't solvable, without  schematic

Comment: sometime failed fans will case problem!, just connect both fans after checking the perfect Voltage to your power supply directly, and make them working all the time, in this case nothing will conflict on your graphic card, and let me know :) of your result

Comment: Ramhound - I have stated that the card does not overheat. Even during gaming time the temperatures shown in GPUZ were very stable (around 127.4 Fahrenheit). During idle it was even less. Anyways great idea with 'circuit level problem'. I didn't think of it that way. Generally speaking, what can cause that type of problems? 

narzan - Thank you. I'll try that asap. In your opinion - is it possible that GPU can detect a fan not working properly and shut down the entire card operation to prevent a critical damage? This would explain a lot :) I'll let you know by updating this  thread asap.

Comment: In a matter of few days I should acquire a laboratory type power supply and I'll be able to check the fans. In case that fans would be damaged - how to install Noctuas or different 3rd party standard 80mm fans on the radiator of GTX 660?

Comment: @narzan Hi there. I've checked the both fans with a laboratory grade power supply with power stabilisation. The fans make tiny rattling noise but work well for up to 0.35 A and 10 Volts. I was afraid to give them more. These fans start to operate as soon as I give them 2.6 Volts. When I manually stop one of the fans, it stops for a few seconds and then begins to operate. To say more - both fans seem to do their job properly even for long periods of time. Any suggestions? I feel quite hopeless with my GTX :)